# Faced Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () when uploaded my react app to github pages

Tags: reactjs

I have created a simple react project and then executed the command npm run build. Then, uploaded to github pages here https://mirzhal95.github.io/customTemplate/ but faced Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). So, I am referencing images like this

```
const store = [

        {
          name: "outside",
          color: "lightpink",
          position: [-400, 0, 300],
          url: "src/assets/picture1.jpg",
          link: 1,
        },
    
        {
          name: "inside",
          color: "lightblue",
          position: [-100, 0, 900],
          url: "src/assets/picture5.jpg",
          link: 2,
        },
        {
          name: "Hall",
          color: "red",
          position: [20, 10, 0],
          url: "src/assets/picture3.jpg",
          link: 1,
        },
      ];
```

How should I reference jpg images so I do not have problems when deployed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying from your dist/ folder, your images need to be in there. Currently they aren't, so you'll probably want to play with your webpack config. You either want to just rollup your entire assets directory, or you'll need to import those images via typescript. Otherwise webpack has no idea that those strings you've got reference actual files.

The easiest thing for testing is to make those links relative to the dist folder, so like:

```
url: "src/assets/picture3.jpg"
```

would become:

```
url: "/assets/picture3.jpg"
```

And then you can copy the asserts folder over to dist/ yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're using Create React App.

You might have to add a `homepage` entry to `package.json` with the name of your repo and then reference them from `https://github-username.github.io/repo-name/image-name.png` if the image is directly in the `public` directory. (Modify the URL as per your directory structure inside the `public` directory.)

Eg: In `package.json`

```json
...
"homepage": "/repo-name",
...
```

[`package.json` example from my project.](https://github.com/HarshKapadia2/git-graph/blob/main/package.json#L5)

Without this `homepage` entry, React.js looks for the resource at `https://github-username.github.io` rather than `https://github-username.github.io/repo-name`.